# How do I define an either rational and irrational sequence, please?

Tags: calculus

I'm interested in this question,because I'm working on a continuity proof for the piecewise function

$f(x)=\begin{cases}\left|{x}\right|&\text{if}& x\in\mathbb{Q}\\0&\text{if}& x\not\in\mathbb{Q}\end{cases}$

based on the following characterization of limits with sequences

If exists $\lim_{x\rightarrow c}{f(x)}$ and $(x_n)$ is a real sequence st $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{x_n}=c$, then $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f(x_n)}=\lim_{x\rightarrow c}{f(x)}$

I've already solved it provided two sequences, one rational and another irrational, but I'd like to solve it for a both rational and irrational sequence. The question is to obtain the expression for such a sequence, I think.

Thanks!

Comment: I assume you are looking at continuity at $x=0$. A sequence of rational numbers is a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ with $x_k = p_k/q_k$ for all $k$, where $p_k, q_k$ are integers with no common factors and $q_k\neq 0$. On the other hand, for this problem I believe you want a sequence $\{x_k\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ with $x_k \in \mathbb{R}$ for all $k$ (so some terms may be rational, others not) such that $x_k\rightarrow 0$.

Comment: If $f(x)=x$ for $x\ne0$, and $f(0)=17$, then $\lim_{x\to 0}f(x)=0$, but if $x_n=0$ for all $n$ then $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x_n)=17$.

Comment: It seems something is missing from your "characterization of limits," and anyway don't you need to prove the limit exists? Have you tried that part yet?

Comment: Thanks, Michael!

Comment: Hi, David k. First thank you for your answer. The limit is zero. It is very likely that the characterization lacks seriousness: the source is a very basic textbook